# Calculating sales tax for digital goods with REST SDK

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to update our website to use the new PayPal v2 API, and have struck a problem handling local sales tax.

We sell digital goods only, so I want to set the `shipping_preference` to `NO_SHIPPING`. But when I do that, we no longer get a callback to `onShippingAddressChange` to tell us the user's country, so we have no way to know whether to add sales tax on or not.

What's the recommended process for handling this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optionally have the payer select a starting country near or above the PayPal button, or base it on their IP.

When onApprove is triggered, you can get the order's payer country before doing the capture and do a patch API call ("update order") if necessary.

---

To show a new total to the payer before capture, you can add an additional order review step. Either set the `user_action` to `CONTINUE` in the API, or specify `&commit=false` when loading the JS SDK.

The last button at PayPal will change from "Pay Now" (default for JS SDK integrations) to "Continue to Review Order".

Correspondingly, when onApprove is triggered, rather than immediately doing the capture first show the revised total to the payer with something for them to confirm the payment that they captures the order.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like a deficiency of the API to require the extra step. It means a purely digital sale actually has a more involved flow for the customer than a physical product would.

Comment: That is the traditional flow, onShipping* functions were added to the JS SDK relatively recently. They have their own limitations, like not supporting the black button inline guest flow (opening in-context window instead)